# Rsync cannot connect to host through slurm

Tags: ssh, slurm, sbatch

I am currently utilizing Slurm to schedule a data transfer using Rsync. I usually connect to the destination server using SSH with the command "ssh user_name@server" and it works without any issues. However, I am having an error when trying to use sbatch for the same task. I got

ssh: Could not resolve hostname server.edu: Temporary failure in name resolution
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]

The script for sbatch in order to schedule the data transfer is below.

````
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=rsync_job
#SBATCH --output=rsync_job_%j.out
#SBATCH --error=rsync_job_%j.err
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1
#SBATCH --time=00:30:00

# Set the source and destination paths
src_path=/source/path
dest_path=/destination/path/

# Use rsync to copy files from source to destination
rsync -avzr --progress $src_path username@server:/dest_path

echo "Rsync job complete"```

Anyone knows how can I schedule the rsync with sbatch


I expect to schedule the data transfer using (slurm, sbatch)
````

Answer (score 0):

The error `Could not resolve hostname server.edu` means the compute node is not able to translate the name of the server into its IP address.

It can be a temporary problem, as the message implies, or simply that compute nodes do not have name resolution configured by design.

To alleviate that problem, you can find out the IP address with the `dig` command (see for instance [this reference](https://www.networkworld.com/article/3527430/digging-up-ip-addresses-with-the-dig-command.html)) and place it in the `rsync` command line, for instance

```
 rsync -avzr --progress $src_path username@12.34.56.78:/dest_path
```